# Android hide the implementation of class?

Tags: java, android, dll, encapsulation

I am new to android development and need some solution for this problem, I have created a class that does some encryption work and have to give that to another person but I can't let them know the implementation of this class, so what i've done is encapsulated the methods..

I read that Creating a jar library is for a complete application.. since i need to give only a single file i can't make a jar library.. 
any solution for this???

Any help would be great.. thanks in advance..

Comment: `since i need to give only a single file i can't make a jar library`, Nope, You can create a jar file with that interface only

Comment: how…? is the same process for creating jar library of android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile your file, create a .class file and give it to them. But before giving take care of following things

1. java version.
2. supporting library required.

Comment: how? can u please explain a bit?

Comment: like it says [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) ??

Comment: wt example u need.. its straight forward.. just search in creating  .class through command line